# makefile rule and separate directories

Tags: makefile, pylint

I have a (gnu) makefile to run pylint on a bunch of scripts. It has the nice feature that pylint only runs on updated scripts. How can I modify this so the lint_report files go to a parallel or sub directory?

```
scripts := $(wildcard *.py)
lint_reports = $(scripts:.py=.lint_report)

all: $(lint_reports)

$(lint_reports): %.lint_report: %.py
    -pylint3 $< > $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
report_dir := otherdir
scripts := $(wildcard *.py)
lint_reports := $(addprefix $(report_dir)/,$(scripts:.py=.lint_report))    

all: $(lint_reports)

$(lint_reports): $(report_dir)/%.lint_report: %.py
    -pylint3 $< > $@
```

Comment: Or `lint_reports := $(patsubst %.py, $(report_dir)/%.lint_report, $(scripts))`

Comment: I used HardcoreHenry's answer with `report_dir := ../lint`. Worked a treat.